# NodeJS "synchronous" function call returns [object Promise]

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express

I wanted to create a platform to learn the power of NodeJS, so I arranged a web application that uses SQLite. I wanted to make the web app show a random post, so I made the web app select one:

`var post = db.run("SELECT post_name FROM posts ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3;")`

When I try to use post to get the entire row that it's results are included in:

`var postrow = db.all("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_name = ${post}") // return object promise`

As you can see, it will return [object Promise], causing a database error since there is no column named like that. But this really confuses me because the column is post_name, post is supposed to be the value, not the column. I have tried a lot (if not all) of the methods I could find, and it still would return [object Promise] no matter what.
I am using NodeJS v18.2.
My full code is:

```
app.get("/home", function(req,res){
 var post1 = db.run("SELECT post_name FROM posts ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3;").then(function(value) {
  return value;
 });
 res.render(__dirname + "/public/index.html", {
  post1: post1,
  postowned: db.run(`SELECT ownedby FROM posts WHERE post_name = ${post1}`)
 })})
```

Edit: The definition of db is:

```
dbWrapper
.open({
 filename: dbFile,
 driver: sqlite3.Database
})
.then(async dBase => {
db = dBase;

try {
  if (!exists) {
    await db.run(
      "CREATE TABLE posts ( post_name VARCHAR(20), post_text TEXT, ownedby VARCHAR(15), cdate TIMESTAMP );"
    );
  }
  console.log(await db.all("SELECT post_name from post"));
} catch (dbError) {
  console.error(dbError);
} });
```

Comment: You are not showing `db` and `app` definition. Based on your code, `db.run` is Asynch. I bet the same is true about db.all.

Comment: Obviously, app is `express()`

Comment: The call is very obviously asynchronous, since it returns a promise. Moreover, you already use it as asynchronous in `await db.run("CREATE TABLE posts ( post_name VARCHAR(20), post_text TEXT, ownedby VARCHAR(15), cdate TIMESTAMP );" );` and `db.run("SELECT post_name FROM posts ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3;").then()`

Comment: And since the `app.get` instance is synchronous, how should I use the asynchronous function properly? (something like `await`)

Comment: Either `await` the promise or use `.then()`. `app.get()` may be synchronous but would only finish processing the request when `res,render()` is called or other methods on `res` that determine the result of the request.

Comment: `await` is invalid in synchronous function calls and I have already used `.then()` with the same results. I have already used both on the 2 variables with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.run` and `db.all` are both asynchronous functions, so they will return [object Promise]. Nonetheless, it is possible to change the value to the actual response by using `db.run`s optional callback parameter, The code below selects a random post:

```
var posts = []
db.run("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3;", function(err, row) {
 if (row.post_name != null){ 
  // if the post name is not null then push it to posts
  posts.push({ title:row.post_name, text:row.post_text, date:row.cdate, owned:row.ownedby})
 }
})
// the columns will be available in posts as 0, 1, it goes on as more posts are selected
```

It is possible to only select columns that you want by using the comma (for instance `SELECT post_name, post_text FROM posts`)

Since `app.get` is a synchronous function, and you can't call it with `async`, this does not use `await`, but this would still work as it won't give the promise response.